# Multiple layouts in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have referred to http://codeboxlabs.com/how-to-create-default-layout-on-codeigniter-using-hook/ for having default layout.

Is it possible to have multiple layout designed in codeigniter?
CASE : There is an select option in header for changing the layouts. On change of select I want to change the layout structure of codeigniter website. 
How can we achieve that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, this is probably the best video I had found so far. It is similar to Asp.net master page.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiiGh-iYPHg

Good luck

Just create new master pages , if you want.